# How to capture ICMP packets instead of ICMPv6 packets via ping?

Tags: wireshark, ping, icmp

I am trying to ping a host and capture the packets using Wireshark. I need to view the results in ICMP so I can view the IP addresses, but Wireshark keeps capturing the packets in ICMPv6 and as a result I can only see MAC addresses. Is there a way to change that?

I've tried looking in the options of my capture interfaces and didn't really find anything helpful. I'm not sure if it's a Wireshark issue or an issue with my system.

Comment: If you are only sending ICMPv6 packets, then you will only see ICMPv6 packets in Wireshark. Wireshark will only show you traffic that it sees. Are you *sure* that you are sending IPv4 pings (or not filtering them out)?

Comment: @RossJacobs I'm silly. In past pings, my system has usually defaulted to IPv4. Didn't realize that I was pinging in IPv6--flew right over my head. Added the -4 tag at the end and it worked out. Thank you